# WebdriverWait is showing TimeoutException, if I use sleep.time it works ok

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to use WebdriverWait for when clicking elements in Python Webdriver.

I get the following TimeoutException error when using WebdriverWait:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py", line 30, in test_add_Project
    administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration()
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\login.py", line 46, in clickAdministration
    WebDriverWait (self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath).click())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:
```

If I use `time.sleep(10)` it works ok and clicks the elements.  I have reverted all my links to time.sleep for now until I can get `WebdriverWait` to work properly.

My code snippet for WebdriverWait is:

```
class LoginPage(BasePage):

    #Click Administration from top menu
    def clickAdministration(self):
        WebDriverWait (self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath).click())
        #time.sleep(10)
        return AdministrationPage(self.driver)
```

The imports are:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_add_Project(self):
        login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
        login_page.userLogin_valid()
        administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration()
```

Is my `WebdriverWait` syntax correct? Why the TimeoutException?

If I use `time.sleep(secs)`, it works fine but not the best efficient way to do it.

Comment: Are you using time.sleep instead of the WebDriverWait?  Is that the entire exception message?

Comment: The exception was showing when i was using WebdriverWait.  Then i reverted to using time.sleep until i fix the syntax for WebdriverWait.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are not using the Explicit Wait correctly - you need to make use of Expected Conditions - callables that would be called repeatedly until return `True`. You are returning the result of `click()` method which returns `None` which is falsy - the expected condition never returns `True` and, hence, you are getting `TimeoutException`.

In this case, built-in [`element_to_be_clickable`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) fits nicely, example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="test"]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: i have used something like `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, i)))` where i is a varibale but I am getting `TimeOutException`. Please point me out the mistake that I am doing here.

Comment: @proprius it heavily depends on a use case, please elaborate into a separate question if you need help and throw a link here. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe here is the link to the question: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827365/timeoutexception-when-use-link-text-with-explicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver-wit/34836229#34836229)

Comment: @proprius thanks, saw it already, thanks. Please provide the HTML representation of the link and include it into that question.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the particular tag I was looking for in html code.

Comment: your answer is perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
paragraph = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > p:nth-child(3)")))
paragraph.getText()
```