# TimeOutException when use link_text with explicit wait in selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception

I am using selenium webdriver with python. I want to use explicit wait for locating element on the basis of the links they are pointing to. For achieving this, I am using

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'dashboard')))
```

Here is the html code for that:

```
<li class="headerLink" name="dashboard"><a href="http://www.xy.com/dashboard" class="touch">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Everytime I run this query, I get `TimeOutException` but if I use `By.ID`, I am able to locate element. I tried to do the same for other websites for which `link_text` worked fine.

If I use without explicit wait, I am able to find elements but with extra modification, I am getting `StaleException`.

I am unable to find the solution for this. Please help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant html?

Comment: `but if I use By.ID, I am able to locate element` - the element you provided does not have an ID. Also, do you see any iframe elements on the page?

Comment: I have tried using `id` for some other tag. No, it doesnt have iframe. Anyhow I am using default_context() everytime I search.

Comment: I also made it to work using xpath. I still dont know why partial_link_text and link_text are not working but with xpath, selenium seem to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not the proper tag for using PartialLinkText ?

**Find element by Partial Link Text**

> Selenium allows you to identify a hyperlink control with a partial
>   text. This can be quite useful when the text is dynamically generated.
>   In other words, the text on one web page might be different on your
>   next visit. We might be able to use the common text shared by these
>   dynamically generated link texts to identify them. // will click the
>   "Cancel" link

Try to use LinkText

> Find element by Link Text For Hyperlinks only. Using a link’s text is
>   probably the most direct way to click a link, as it is what we see on
>   the page.

Comment: I have tried LINK_TEXT too but it doesnt seem to work